# CSS Code don't work on react.js centering width

Tags: css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

Hi guys so I'm trying to create an web application using react-bootstrap and I wanted to change the width of my row and center it. I already make the css and js file but I cannot center the row. I tried moving my code to codesandbox and it work just fine. anyone know why ?

My code:

```
            <Container fluid>
                <Row className="roomfac fontReg">
                    <Col lg={3} className="text-center">
                       <img src="./Images/logofridge.png" alt="Logo 1"/>
                       <h3 className="fontSB">Fridge</h3>
                    </Col>

                    <Col lg={3} className="text-center">
                       <img src="./Images/logoAC.png" alt="Logo 2"/>
                       <h3 className="fontSB">AC</h3>
                    </Col>

                    <Col lg={3} className="text-center">
                       <img src="./Images/logowifi2.png" alt="Logo 3"/>
                       <h3 className="fontSB">Wifi</h3>
                    </Col>

                    <Col lg={3} className="text-center">
                       <img src="./Images/logotv.png" alt="Logo 4"/>
                       <h3 className="fontSB">TV</h3>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </Container>
```

My CSS Code:

```
.roomfac {
    display: flex;
    width: 60%;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: Have you checked by inspecting that your CSS is applying perfectly?

Comment: yes I have, the display flex for roomfac class is slashed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working for me too in chrome as well as edge, make sure whether your css files are included correctly or else try using inline css in jsx.

```
<Row style={{display:"flex",width: "60%",margin: "auto",justifyContent: "center"}} className="fontReg">
```

Comment: Thanks, It work perfectly fine when i change it into inline css

Comment: Can somebody explain why this is not working while using "className"?

Comment: @SamDani I used to check it, but it is working for me, I think he/she doen't includes external css properly.